# Product of characters

Tags: java

I´m buzzy with problem 8 of the Project Euler series. 
The question was the following: "Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number." followed by a string of 1000 digits.

I've written the following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "7316717653133062..."; //note string is 1000 digits
    int answer = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 995; i++) {
        char Char1 = s.charAt(i);
        char Char2 = s.charAt(i +1);
        char Char3 = s.charAt(i +2);
        char Char4 = s.charAt(i+ 3);
        char Char5 = s.charAt(i + 4);

        int product = Char1 * Char2 * Char3* Char4 * Char5;

        if(product > answer) {
            answer = product;
        }

    }

System.out.println(answer);
}
```

but I get an answer that is way to big. (570394440)
I don't know where the mistake is (eclipse couldnt find one either), so I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: The character value of a number character is not it's value.  For instance, a `'1`' is not int value 1, it's 49 (I believe).

Comment: Could the **real** issue at hand by an **Integer overflow**? There is nothing wrong with multiplying `char` values as far as I know, conceptually, even though this is not what the OP wants to do.

Comment: Your algorithm is good though, you only need to multiply the figures, and not the character values. And tag it "Euler-Project"

Comment: @AndrewThompson Youre right, I use to do that, but I guess with copying something went wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are multiplying character values, not digit values.

`'3' != 3`, but `'3' - '0' == 3`, this is because `'3'` is a character representation of the integer value 3, and is actually 51, the ASCII value used to represent '3'.

All of the character representations of the numbers are in order, beginning with '0', which has an ASCII value of 48.

Because they are in order, you need to subtract `'0'` from the character values prior to multiplying them, which in turn implicitly converts them into their digit values (0-9).

Like so (Edit, removed unnecessary casting back to `char`):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

    int answer = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 995; i++) {
        int Char1 = s.charAt(i + 0) - '0';
        int Char2 = s.charAt(i + 1) - '0';
        int Char3 = s.charAt(i + 2) - '0';
        int Char4 = s.charAt(i + 3) - '0';
        int Char5 = s.charAt(i + 4) - '0';

        int product = Char1 * Char2 * Char3* Char4 * Char5;

        if(product > answer) {
            answer = product;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Could you please clarify?

Comment: The character value of '1' is 49, its ASCII code. That's why you subtract by '0': to form an implicit cast to integer and thus its digit value.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Yeah, I get that, I thought you meant something else.

Comment: He means to include it in you response.  Giving an answer without explaining it is a poor practice.

Comment: Nope, just adding information ;) Keep in mind that an answer should explain **why** something is happening, not just how to solve it.

Comment: @SteveP. I'm actually working on that right now, although I did mention originally that he was multiplying *character* values instead of *digit* values.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel So you're "just adding information", but "an answer should explain **why** something is happening."  Was there really an need to contradict me, then?

Comment: @SteveP.: we posted within seconds from eachother, it was meant towards Robbie.

Comment: @SteveP. I've revised my answer and provided more information for any future readers.

Answer (score 3):

The value of the `char` variable is not the same as the digit character it represents. Use this:

```
char char1 = (char) (s.charAt(i) - '0');
```

and so on.

EDIT: Also, please note the notation conventions for Java: fields and local variables are not capitalized.